# left alignment in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

[image]

I have space restriction and can give only the space mentioned in the table structure below. My concern is how to justify to left, the contents in cells so that the text Height, weight etc will be completely inside the table. I saw that, instead of `|ccc|` we can use `|lll|` or `|rrr|` ... but here I have `|m{0.5cm}|` and I don't know how to change.

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
%\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering \caption{Details}
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|}
   % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
   \hline
 No.& Age {[years]}  & Height {[cm]} & Weight {[kg]}\\\hline
  11&  56& 160& 88 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}\label{10_PKPD}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I also tried to modify one line from above code as below

```
\begin{tabular}{|{\raggedright}m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|m{0.5cm}|}
```

which gives error. Please help

Thank you

Comment: Using `m{0.5cm}` already left aligns the contents of a cell (but with justification), but the cell gets a width of 0.5cm no matter what. Now TeX tries to put the stuff of one cell into this width like it does for a `\parbox`. The problem is that it can't linebreak "Weight". In other words: It is not possible without changing a size (be it the fontsize or the column width).

Comment: Thank u for your comment, but looking at the table, its like "Age" is in the middle and "Height " is towards right

Comment: It isn't. They are leftaligned. You are tricked by the fact that there is a bit of padding around the cell (one `\tabcolsep`) and the fact that "Age" has a width of around 0.5cm which is why it does look centred. If you want to inject stuff like `\raggedright` into a column you can do this with the `array`-package. The syntax is `>{pre-cell-content}m{0.5cm}<{post-cell-content}`. So using `\raggedright` would look like: `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}`. The `\arraybackslash` is to restore the `\\ ` inside a `tabular` (`\raggedright` changes it).

Comment: Even the unreadable `\tiny` font size gives `Overfull \hbox` messages. Can't you really use larger tables?  `tabularx{\linewidth}` would have no problem.

Comment: I'd also say that the best approach is change stuff so that you can use more horizontal space.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. Actually I have brought in a slice of the table, the real table has more columns and hence the size limitation.

Comment: Can I make it centerered retaining the m-width option? I ask this so that, in that case the text "Height" will leave equal space on either sides and look like the text "Age" and will be inside the box too.

Comment: Other suggestion: Rotate the column header. That will save horizontal space.

Comment: It is possible to centre it, but this won't help on the alignment (it does get centred but if it's too wide gets left adjusted). To centre the contents of the column I'd use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}` for the column specification.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're bound to the column width of .5 cm, I'd suggest abbreviating your header texts adding some footnotes at the end of the table.

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
%\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering\caption{Details\label{10_PKPD}}% put label near caption
\begin{tabular}{|C{0.5cm}|C{0.5cm}|C{0.5cm}|C{0.5cm}|}
   % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
   \hline
 No.& A  & H & W\\\hline
  11&  56& 160& 88 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \rule{0pt}{9pt}A = Age [years]\\
    H = Height [cm]\\
    W = Weight [kg]\\
    \end{tabular}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering\caption{A better layout\label{better}}% put label near caption
\begin{tabular}{C{0.5cm}C{0.5cm}C{0.5cm}C{0.5cm}}
   % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
   \toprule
 No.& A  & H & W\\\midrule
  11&  56& 160& 88 \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \rule{0pt}{9pt}A = Age [years]\\
    H = Height [cm]\\
    W = Weight [kg]\\
    \end{tabular}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]